# Nunit, test exception thrown by event handler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, nunit

I have 2 classes, server and client, and I'd like to test that the server throws an exception when the client sends an unknown or wrong data type.

I wrote the following but it doesn't work since it's not the Send function that throws the exception:

```
    // Unit test
    var serverEventRaised = new ManualResetEvent( false );
    Assert.That( () =>
    {
        _server.DataReceived += ( sender, args ) =>
        {
            // Should not reach here since exception should be thrown before raising event
            Console.WriteLine( "Server received data" );
            serverEventRaised.Set();
        };

        _client.Send( new[] { "html", "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>test</body></html>" } );
    }, Throws.Exception.TypeOf< Exception >() );

    Assert.That( serverEventRaised.WaitOne( 5000 ), Is.False );
```

The server itself gets the event from its socket before raising another event:

```
    // Server class
    public event EventHandler< CustomEventArgs > DataReceived;

    private void OnMessageReceived( object sender, MySocketEventArgs args )
    {
        var dataType = args.Data[ 0 ].GetString();

        switch ( dataType )
        {
            case "text":
                // Do something
                break;
            case "image":
                // Do something else
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception( "Unknown type" );
        }

        // Raise DataReceived event
        var handler = DataReceived;
        handler?.Invoke( this, new CustomEventArgs( args.Data[ 1 ] ) );
    }
```

Sorry if the explanations are difficult to understand, hard to explain and typing with 1 hand :(

Comment: Could you create a mock client object and fake the client sending the wrong data type?

Comment: I think that wouldn't trigger the OnMessageReceived method in the server class, so it would never throw the Exception for unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking for a way of doing roughly the same thing. This is the approach I subsequently took:

```
...
bool exceptionWasThrown = false;

try
{
   _client.Send( new[] { "html", "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>test</body></html>" } );
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //Check the exception details here too

   exceptionWasThrown = true;
}

Assert.IsTrue(execptionWasThrown);
```